# How change format time from jSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I use a jSpinner to choose and save time.

I want enter the start time for a task in the database. But the format that saves the database is this: Tue Apr 15 17:24:56 BST 2014

I want in HH:mm.

This is the code I use to write the data in the database:

```
    public void UpdateTask() {
    try {
        Task t1 = new Task();
        t1.setIdTask(jTIdTask.getText());
        t1.setDate(jTDate.getText());

        ---->  t1.setHourBegin(jSpinner2.getValue().toString());  // This is what I need change

        TaskDao dao = new TaskDao();
        dao.updateTask(t1);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(jTTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

#### CLASS DAO

```
  public void updateTask(Taskst1) throws SQLException{
    String sql = "update Taskset idTask=?, date=?, hourBegin=? where idTask=?"; 
    PreparedStatement stmt = this.conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setString(1, st1.getIdTask());
    stmt.setString(2, st1.getDate());
    stmt.setString(3, st1.getHourBegin());
    stmt.setString(4, st1.getIdTask());

    stmt.execute();
    stmt.close();
    conexao.close();
}
```

#### FORM

[image]

[image]

---

#### SOLUTION

```
   public void UpdateTask() {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Task t1 = new Task();
        t1.setIdTask(jTIdTask.getText());
        t1.setDate(jTDate.getText());

        String time = sdf.format(jSpinner2.getValue());
        t1.setHourBegin(time);

        TaskDao dao = new TaskDao();
        dao.updateTask(t1);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(jTTask.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question with a working code sample. Please post your code as an [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Duncan. I edit my question, I hope I have explained better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jSpinner2.getValue().toString()` is basically asking the returned object for whatever `String` representation it has, in this instance, you're asking a `Date` object to pass you back it's default `String` representation.

Remember, `Date` does not have any concept of a format, it's just a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

You will need to use a `DateFormatter` of some kind to format the `Date` value from the `JSpinner` to the format you want...

A better solution would be to use some kind of date/time data type in you database...

**Updated**

The stored in the `JSpinner` is a `Date` object, it has no concept of a format.  You will need to use some kind of `DateFormatter` to take to from been a `Date` to been a `String` value formatted the way you want.

```
Object value = jSpinner2.getValue();
if (value instanceof Date) {
    String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(value);
    t1.setHourBegin(time);
} else {
    // Deal with the invalid value...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @MadProgrammer. Is it possible to explain in a more practical way please?

Comment: What format do you want the value from the `JSpinner` to be in...? Or simply change your database so that the value is stored as some kind of date/time stamp value instead

Comment: Thanks for help. I worked around what you said and managed to solve my problem. Thanks again for the help.