# Getting the TIME value from JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jspinner

I'm quite new to java programming and I have created a java program that enables user to input the time (HH:mm:ss format) using a JSpinner on a JFrame. It was made through customizing the JSPinner's code (shown below). What I'm trying to do is to get the value (Time) that was input by the user and convert it to string displayed on a JLabel. I've tried using the state change event but for integer models only.

**JSPinner's customized code**

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

time_spinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);

JSpinner.DateEditor te = new JSpinner.DateEditor(time_spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
time_spinner.setEditor(te);

getContentPane().add(time_spinner, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(120, 50, 120, 30));
```

Comment: `JSpinner#getValue` will return a `Date` value representing the "time" of the spinner - the basic concept is demonstrated at [How to use spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23103328/how-change-formate-time-from-jspinner-solved/23103458#23103458)

Comment: How do I pass the received value to a JLabel or somewhere? I tried printing it out on the console to test, but nothing is returned. I used your example object value = time_spinner.getValue().toString(); and the if statement but removed the format HH:mm, and tried to print it out using System.out.print(value) @MadProgrammer

Comment: Observing the codes, mine doesn't seem to read the value as an instance of Date. The else condition was executed instead.

Comment: Since all I have a is an out-of-context snippet of code, it's impossible for me to comment further

Comment: Thanks, greatly appreciated! I was able to understand the answer you posted and managed  to put it to my program and solved my case. Let me know how I could help with anything, I cant up-vote yet but I want to help back. @MadProgrammer

Comment: There should be a little green tick next to the answer, if it solved your problem you can mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of your question, `JSpinner#getValue` will return a `Date` object.  You need to take the `Date` object and format it in what ever manner is required for you (for example `HH:mm:ss`)

This is demonstrate at [How to use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html), which would be worth your time reading

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JSpinner time_spinner;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            Date date = new Date();
            SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

            time_spinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner(sm);

            JSpinner.DateEditor te = new JSpinner.DateEditor(time_spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
            time_spinner.setEditor(te);

            add(time_spinner, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Show me the time");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Object value = time_spinner.getValue();
                    if (value instanceof Date) {
                        Date date = (Date)value;
                        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        String time = format.format(date);

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "The time is " + time);
                    }
                }
            });
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

}
```